# Validate list in view using annotations

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-chosen

In my solution I am using listbox to disply list like bellow & also I am using Chosen.js so that I can choose multiple records.

```
@Html.ListBox("AllLanguages", new SelectList(ViewBag.Languages, "Id", "Language1"))


<div id="languagesDiv"></div>
```

using jquery I am creting hidden fields for my model binded property like bellow

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#AllLanguages").chosen();

        $("#AllLanguages").on("change", function () {
            $("#languagesDiv").empty();
            var languagesCount = 0;
            $("#AllLanguages option:selected").each(function () {
                var lang = "<input type='hidden' id='MovieLanguages[" + languagesCount + "].LanguageId' name='MovieLanguages[" + languagesCount + "].LanguageId' value='" + $(this).val() + "' />";

                $("#languagesDiv").append(lang);
                languagesCount++;
            });
        });
    });
```

What this Jquery will do is , it will create hidden fields for each selected values like bellow

```
  <input type='hidden' id='MovieLanguages[0].LanguageId' name='MovieLanguages[0].LanguageId' value='1' />
  <input type='hidden' id='MovieLanguages[1].LanguageId' name='MovieLanguages[1].LanguageId' value='2' />
```

Now I want to make sure that user should select atleast one value from listbox.

My Model property for this is list

```
     public IList<Language> MovieLanguages { get; set; }
```

I tried using `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.MovieLanguages)` but this does not work.

How to validate this ?
If there is any better way to do this, then please let me know

Comment: There is no validation attribute that suits your needs. You can always count the selected options and if zero, prevent the submit and display an error message. But why are you creating hidden inputs? - your `AllLanguages` property contains the values of the selected options when you submit the form

Comment: @StephenMuecke how can I bind selected values to my Model property directly ? updated question with model property

Comment: You view model needs a property `IEnumerable<int> SelectedLanguages`  and then its `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedLanguages, new SelectList(ViewBag.Languages, "Id", "Language1"))` and when you submit, the value of `SelectedLanguages` will contain all the selected ID's (although I recommend your view model contain a property `SelectList Languages` rather than using `ViewBag`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke but doing my way binds data directly with "IList<Language> MovieLanguages". If I do it your way then I have to loop through the "SelectedLanguages " & make List.

Comment: Why would you need to make a list (you only save the ID's to the database, not to mention you 'list' only has the `ID` property set anyway). And what happen if your `Language` model has any validation attributes - you model will be invalid and then you will need more awful hacks.

Answer (score 0):

An HTML select element can only return simple types: int, string, etc. You cannot post a full `Language` object from a select input. Therefore, you need a property that you can bind to that will accept a list of language ids:

```
public List<int> SelectedLanguageIds { get; set; }
```

Then, in your view:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedLanguageIds, new SelectList(ViewBag.Languages, "Id", "Language1"))
```

In your post action, then, you can use this list to lookup the associated `Language` objects:

```
var selectedLanguages = db.Languages.Where(m => model.SelectedLanguageIds.Contains(m.Id));
```

In order to require that at least one be selected, just use the `Required` attribute like on any other property.

Comment: I did the same way. But some how validation for "SelectedLanguageIds " is not applying. I added "  [Required]" attribute in my viewmodel for this property. This is due to I am using chosen.js.